# How to mount TP-Link "Network Neighborhood" (SMB) on Linux with mount.cifs

Tags: linux, networking, mount, samba

What are the "right" options to mount TP-Link "Network Neighborhood" (SMB) on Linux with mount.cifs? Apparently using defaults is not enough:

```
mount.cifs //hostname/sda1/ /mnt/n -v -o user=xxx,pass=yyy
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.0.1,unc=\\hostname\sda1,user=xxx,pass=********
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge of TP-Link hardware/software version and mount.cifs version is crucial here. Check the documentation and explicitly provide the version info to mount.cifs. E.g., Archer C9 supports only SMB 1.0, so add it to the options:

```
# mount.cifs //hostname/sda1/ /mnt/n -v -o rw,user=xxx,pass=yyy,vers=1.0
```

or via /etc/fstab

```
//hostname/sda1 /mnt/n cifs rw,user=xxx,pass=yyy,vers=1.0 0 1
```